# Angular 10 - AuthError - Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I tried to add Amplify Authenticator component to an Angular app but got an Auth Error. The app uses Angular 10.1.1 and Amplify 3.3.1.  Amplify framework was configured with an existing Authentication resource.

This worked earlier with Angular 8 and Amplify 1.3.3. The issue occurred after Migrating it into the above mentioned versions.

[image]

Below are Some details of the application:

- Amplify Status

  [image]
- package.json

  ```json
  {
  "name": "cg-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.1",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "^0.4.6",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.3.1",
    "boxicons": "^2.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
  }
  ```
- app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { AmplifyUIAngularModule } from '@aws-amplify/ui-angular';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import 'boxicons';

import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component';
import { MainNavigationComponent } from './main-navigation/main-navigation.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import awsconfig from "../../src/aws-exports";

Amplify.Logger.LOG_LEVEL = "DEBUG";

const amplifyConfig = {
  Auth: {
      identityPoolId: awsconfig.aws_cognito_identity_pool_id,
      region: awsconfig.aws_project_region,
      identityPoolRegion: awsconfig.aws_cognito_region,
      userPoolId: awsconfig.aws_user_pools_id,
      userPoolWebClientId: awsconfig.aws_user_pools_web_client_id,
      mandatorySignIn: false,
      authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
      oauth: {
          domain: awsconfig.oauth.domain,
          scope: awsconfig.oauth.scope,
          redirectSignIn: awsconfig.oauth.redirectSignIn,
          redirectSignOut: awsconfig.oauth.redirectSignOut,
          responseType: awsconfig.oauth.responseType 
      }
  }
}
Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig)
const currentConfig = Auth.configure();


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, AuthComponent, MainNavigationComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AmplifyUIAngularModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    MatIconModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

- aws-exports.js file

```js
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.

const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_content_delivery_bucket": "xxxx-xxxx-20190930101956-hostingbucket-dev",
    "aws_content_delivery_bucket_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_content_delivery_url": "http://xxxx-xxxx-20190930101956-hostingbucket-dev.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "us-east-1:xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx",
    "aws_cognito_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "us-east-1_xxXXxxxX",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "oauth": {
        "domain": "xx-xxx-dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com",
        "scope": [
            "phone",
            "email",
            "openid",
            "profile",
            "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
        ],
        "redirectSignIn": "https://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/dashboard/,http://localhost:4200/dashboard/",
        "redirectSignOut": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/,http://localhost:4200/",
        "responseType": "code"
    },
    "federationTarget": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
};


export default awsmobile;
```

- auth.component.html

```html
<div class="container">
        <div style="margin-top: 30px">
          <amplify-authenticator
            *ngIf="authState !== 'signedin'"
          ></amplify-authenticator>

          <div *ngIf="authState === 'signedin' && user" class="App">
            <amplify-sign-out></amplify-sign-out>
            <div>Hello, {{ user.username }}</div>
            <!-- This is where you application template code goes -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

- auth.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef  } from '@angular/core';
import { onAuthUIStateChange, CognitoUserInterface, AuthState } from '@aws-amplify/ui-components';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth',
  templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth.component.css'],
})
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
  user: CognitoUserInterface | undefined;
  authState: AuthState;
  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
   
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    onAuthUIStateChange((authState, authData) => {
      this.authState = authState;
      this.user = authData as CognitoUserInterface;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    return onAuthUIStateChange;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to `src/main.ts`:

```js
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import aws_exports from "./aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(aws_exports);
```

Also check out the updated setup guide if this does not solve everything to make sure the other steps are configured properly: https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/angular#connect-frontend-to-api

Comment: I tried adding it but it also didn't work. So, I created a new angular app with Amplify and it worked without any issues. It looks like the configurations are also same in both apps but the older app still doesn't work.

Comment: Quick Update: Seems like it is an issue in my Angular app. So, I created a new app and configured Amplify with it. Then it worked.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Deleting both `node-modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and then run `npm install` fixed the issue. Maybe this is a more lightweight approach than recreating the whole project.